# Explanation of annotations routing with symfony,

Tags: symfony

I want to ask you a little explanations of routing with annotations.

Is there a difference between

```
/**
*@Route("/{_locale"}
*/
```

and :

```
/**
*@Route("/{locale"}
*/
```

Thanks !

Comment: There is no - they are both syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @scoolnico how do you know it's what OP meant?

Comment: @zerkms I'm sorry, I do not understand what you mean

Comment: @scoolnico you have changed the meaning of the question. Now it's different from OP asked initially.

Comment: Nope, I've just changed the code synthax.

Comment: @scoolnico that's right. And you're assuming that's what OP has actually in the code, which may not be the case. It's harmful to not let OP to fix their mistakes, since they don't learn otherwise.

Comment: Com'on dude... the question is about the difference between `_locale` and `locale`...

Comment: @scoolnico just let OP realise that `"` and `)` cannot be put in random places. Do not make them thinking they can put any rubbish here and it will be corrected by community.

Answer (score 1):

Certain parameters with an underscore in a route have special meaning for the resulting `Request` object. So your first route will change the locale setting, such that you can do `$request->getLocale()`, while your second route will set a parameter called locale e.g. `$request->get('locale')`. Special parameters can have a knock on effect for the rest of your application e.g. setting the response format.

The different "special" routing parameters are detailed in the [routing documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#special-routing-parameters). Both are syntactically correct.